# Custom Cell content doesn't take up the entire width of the Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, custom-cell

When I stretch the cell in the .xib file everything works, but when I run the app, the content of the cell doesn't fill the entire space (first image). The cell itself and Content View in it take whole space (second image). I've set constraints of the Bg View like trailing = Bg View.trailing
(Bg View is this view that doesn't want to stretch)

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjlMD.png)
[Debug View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUqLy.png)

It's my first question, I'm sorry if it's not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching for the solution I decided to start over. I deleted the .xib file, made a new cell and now it's working great.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sLoT.png)